# Is there a term for this concept involving functions?

Tags: functions, terminology

If $f_1:X_1\to Y_1$, $\ldots$, $f_n:X_n\to Y_n$ are maps, is there a term for the map $\left(x_1,\ldots,x_n\right)\mapsto\left(f_1\left(x_1\right),\ldots,f_n\left(x_n\right)\right)$ from $X_1\times\cdots\times X_n$ to $Y_1\times\cdots\times Y_n$? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Cartesian product of the functions $f_i$ and is denoted $f_1 \times \cdots \times f_n$.
See for example this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cartesian_product_of_functions).